# Remove comments and logs from AngularJs App while pushing it on Google App Engine

Tags: angularjs, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a `NodeJs App` and I am trying to push the app on `Google Cloud App Engine`. I want to ask how can we `remove comments, logs` from all files e.g `console.log(), //hello, /* hello */` while pushing the app.

I am doing this because after deploying my `Angularjs app` I don't want the client to see any comments or logs on the `browser side`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use [Uglifyjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs).

You can remove all comments and `console.log()` from a file like this:

```
$ uglifyjs -c drop_console=true -o new_file.js file.js
```

By default, *Uglify* will drop all comments, and you can add `drop_console` compression option to remove console calls.

Next you can do a deployment script that make it happens for all the files of your *Angular* app, before you push on your server.